# Problems setting PHP exec path in MAMP after update to El Capitan

Tags: php, apache, mamp

For something that should be so simple, I'm finding it maddeningly difficult to set the path that PHP `exec()` commands use under MAMP on a Mac running El Capitan.

I need the solution to use environment variables rather than (for example) PHP's `putenv()` or a hardcoded "PATH=foo && ", as this code will be used on different servers that each may use a different path. I had it working fine on Yosemite (though, to be honest, I can't remember what finally worked), but when I upgraded to El Capitan the path was reset.

I've tried the following, and have restarted the computer after each just to be entirely sure that Apache's path was being reset:

- Added to path in `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d`
- Added `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin` to `MAMP/Library/bin/_envvars`
- Even set path in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` after disabling SIP to make it possible.
- *Edit to add*: Also tried a symbolic link to somewhere in the default path, but LaTeX, for example, really needs to live on the path.

After each of these, the path (as indicated by a "exec('echo $PATH', $output);" command in the PHP) remains the same:

```
\/usr\/bin:\/bin:\/usr\/sbin:\/sbin
```

I'm at wit's end. If anybody's managed to set the path on a similar setup, I'd love to get input on how it was done.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to let you know: You're not alone. I have tried for hours now without success.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I still haven't found a better solution than symbolic links (which, as I say, is only a partial solution)...

Answer (score 0):

On Mavericks it worked like this:
  - Stop MAMP
  - Rename the file `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars_` to  `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars` (without underscore).
  - Add these two lines at the end of the renamed file:

```
PATH="$PATH:/additional/path1:/additional/path2"
export $PATH
```

- Start MAMP and have a look into `phpinfo()` Output